# How to get the right telegram channel id?

Tags: telegram

- If I get `user_id`, by `contacts.resolveUsername#bf0131c` and search by string `channel`, then I get `user_id = 0x0827ac18`

> If send it to `messages.getFullChat#3b831c66`, then receive error `PEER_ID_INVALID`.
>
> If send if to `users.getFullUser#ca30a5b1`, then I get error `USER_ID_INVALID`.

- If I search string `channel` using `contacts.search#11f812d8`, then I get two user with username `ChannelBot` and `Channel_Bot`, but not get with user or channel name `channel`.

---

1. How get channel id for using in `messages.getFullChat#3b831c66`?
2. How get `chat_id` by name?

Comment: what library are you using to work with telegram API?

Comment: https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Answer (score 19):

Just Simply Forward a message from your channel to This Bot: 
(https://telegram.me/getidsbot)

Comment: NOTICE My channel id starts with '-'

Comment: This bot is currently down. But there is an alternative. Check my answer bellow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946513/6736591

Answer (score 10):

How to get the chat_id for a private channel:

Make it public, give it an @ChannelName
Send message to this channel through your bot API or cURL

https://api.telegram.org/bot111:222/sendMessage?chat_id=@channelName&text=123

It will return the channel id!

```
{ "ok" : true, "result" : { "chat" : { "id" : -?????????, "title" : "Test Private Channel", "type" : "channel" }, "date" : X, "message_id" : 7, "text" : "XXXXXX" } }
```

Now you can convert the channel to private and use the chat_id!

Comment: This doesn't use the API, but it works.

It also works for public channels, just skip the parts about making it public and then private again.

Answer (score 1):

The Telegram API Supports this directly. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods. Look at method `getChat`

1. Convert Your channel to a public channel and create a temporarily memorable name like `'TestChannel123_temp'`
2. Run the following cmdlet (powershell)

   ```
   PS C:\Users\Me> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN_HERE/getChat?chat_id=@publicId"

     ok result
     -- ------
   True @{id=-YOUR_CHAT_ID; title=YOUR_CHAT_TITLE; username=YOUR_CHAT_USERNAME; type=supergroup; photo=}


   PS C:\Users\Me>
   ```
3. Convert 
   group back to private.
4. Send messages via know chat Id.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Telegram Channel ID from @JsonDumpBot]

You can simply forward a message to [@JsonDumpBot](http://t.me/JsonDumpBot).

The bot dumps a complete `json` of all request that he receives.

NOTE: I'm not affiliate and it's not my bot.